# VBA Search List box

Tags: listbox, search-box

I use a userform to search in all worksheets and get sheet name for the found items.

My question is , i don't want the vba to search in all sheets, i just want to search in the first 4 sheets only , or to specify sheets names that i want to search in

i'm using this code , so please if you could assist on how to modify this code to make it search in only specific sheets

Quote
Private Sub TextBox1_Change()

Dim searchkey As Variant
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range
Dim cvalue As Variant

searchkey = TextBox1.Value
Set wb = ThisWorkbook

Me.ListBox1.Clear

For Each ws In wb.Worksheets

Set rng = ws.UsedRange

For Each cvalue In rng

If InStr(1, cvalue, searchkey, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
On Error Resume Next
ListBox1.AddItem cvalue
ListBox1.List(ListBox1.ListCount - 1, 1) = ws.Name
'ListBox1.List(ListBox1.ListCount - 1, 2) = cvalue.Address

End If

Next cvalue

Next ws

End Sub
UnQuote

I tried to make the VBA search only in the first 4 sheets , but actually it is searching in all sheets in workbook including sheets of power query and pivot tables